# How can I create linked invocations on my object in Java to execute a set of instructions by chaining methods together?

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee

I'm learning Java and want to implement method chaining to build a set of execution instructions. I've heard about some design patterns like builder or command pattern (I don't know what those patterns are btw, just heard their names floating around in my learning journey). But not sure if I would be complicating things if I chose to go with a OOP design pattern.

So this is what I want to build:

Hypothetically speaking, lets say I have a class in my program called DatabaseOperator.
In terms of design, I would I go about designing the class so that the client that uses DatabaseOperator could use it like shown below:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        DatabaseOperator do = new DatabaseOperator();
        DatabaseOperator.getConfigurations("fileName").getAuthenticationDetails("somefile").
        joinCluster("clusterName").launchMode("TEST").initiateConnection();
}
```

How should I design my DatabaseOperator class? Any particular design pattern I can use or is it not needed?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Chain of responsibility" and "command" (and/or "interpreter") pattern(s).

Comment: [Fluent interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could design your `DatabaseOperator` class to support chained invocations, by returning the `this` object in the different methods. Each of these methods will update the state of the `DatabaseOperator` in order to facilitate proper execution of other methods (such as `initiateConnection()`) down the line.

As Jordao pointed out, this looks more like a Fluent Interface (that uses a Builder pattern under the hood). One possible implementation could be:

```
public class DatabaseOperator {



    private Configuration configuration = Configuration.DEFAULT;
    private AuthDetails authDetails = AuthDetails.DEFAULT;

    public DatabaseOperator withConfigurationsFrom(String fileName) {
        //Get the configurations from the file, and initialize the 'Configuration' object
        configuration = initializeFrom(fileName);
        return this;
    }

    public DatabaseOperator withAuthenticationDetailsFrom(String fileName) {
        // Get authentication details from the file, and initialize AuthenticationDetails
        authDetails = initializeAuthDetailsFrom(fileName);
        return this;
    }

    //.. and so on

    public void initiateConnection() {
        //Uses configuration and authDetails
    }

}
```

Comment: why you are returning them to this ?

Comment: What's the alternative? I mean if the methods return object of type Configuration for example, How would I do the chaining without the this object?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for pointing out the more likely situation, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @TazMan In order to facilitate chained invocations, you may have to return the same object. However, each method could internally alter the 'Configuration' or 'AuthenticationDetails' objects - and these would play a role in how the subsequent methods (like initiateConnection()) would behave.